# In C# would it be better to use Queue.Synchronized or lock() for thread safety?

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I have a Queue object that I need to ensure is thread-safe. Would it be better to use a lock object like this:

```
lock(myLockObject)
{
//do stuff with the queue
}
```

Or is it recommended to use Queue.Synchronized like this:

```
Queue.Synchronized(myQueue).whatever_i_want_to_do();
```

From reading the MSDN docs it says I should use Queue.Synchronized to make it thread-safe, but then it gives an example using a lock object. From the MSDN article:

> To guarantee the thread safety of the
>   Queue, all operations must be done
>   through this wrapper only.
>
> Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is
>   synchronized, other threads can still
>   modify the collection, which causes
>   the enumerator to throw an exception.
>   To guarantee thread safety during
>   enumeration, you can either lock the
>   collection during the entire
>   enumeration or catch the exceptions
>   resulting from changes made by other
>   threads.

If calling Synchronized() doesn't ensure thread-safety what's the point of it? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Personally I always prefer locking. It means that *you* get to decide the granularity. If you just rely on the Synchronized wrapper, each individual operation is synchronized but if you ever need to do more than one thing (e.g. iterating over the whole collection) you need to lock anyway. In the interests of simplicity, I prefer to just have one thing to remember - lock appropriately!

EDIT: As noted in comments, if you *can* use higher level abstractions, that's great. And if you *do* use locking, be careful with it - document what you expect to be locked where, and acquire/release locks for as short a period as possible (more for correctness than performance). Avoid calling into unknown code while holding a lock, avoid nested locks etc.

In .NET 4 there's a *lot* more support for higher-level abstractions (including lock-free code). Either way, I still wouldn't recommend using the synchronized wrappers.

Comment: Maybe add something about lock-free structures? They don't warrant a new reply.

Comment: @Jonathan: Not sure what there is to say about lock-free structures in this particular case. I generally don't bother trying to go lock-free - it involves a *lot* of head-scratching, and I can't remember *ever* being in a synchronization-bottleneck situation.

Comment: It is better to just use a thread safe container, than to implement its thread safety by yourself for each time you need one.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich: But the thread-safe container isn't really thread-safe for all purposes. It isolates *individual* operations, but what do you do when you need *compound* operations? Additionally, I often find that if I need to do something with a collection, I *also* need to do something with one of the other fields in the class. Of course, this assumes you're not going to expose the collection itself in your API - which would be a bad idea to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The question said "I need my queue to be thread safe". I think a proper answer along your line of thought is "Don't use a thread safe queue, you probably don't need it, use a private queue, and lock on before actions that uses it". Regardless, as JCIP says, I think that locks are often the wrong answer to the concurrency problem. You can solve many cases by thread safe message queues, and worker threads etc..

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich: It depends what the queue is being used for. You seem to be *assuming* a publisher/consumer scenario. These days I'd definitely use the .NET 4 concurrent queues for *that* sort of work - but bear in mind that this was back in 2008, and the OP really wasn't clear about the *use* of this queue. I stand by my approach of *not* using the synchronized wrappers. Depending on the situation there may well be other approaches than locking - but the synchronized wrappers are very rarely the best alternative, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm not assuming a publisher subscriber. I'm rather saying that many problems can redesigned to fit a worker-queue/map-reduce/whatever pattern that can use high level concurrency pattern and does not use locking, even if they're not initially a publisher-subscriber problem. And if this is the case, you'd better use this approach, since locking have a very good potential for hard to detect bugs, even top notch concurrency expert do bugs with locking, you will too. So I would at least mention that in the answer. (I didn't invent that, JCIP did)

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich: You keep mentioning JCIP, but this isn't a Java question - and at the time I wrote the answer, the higher level abstractions available in java.util.concurrent simply weren't present in .NET. Now .NET 4 makes a lot of that simpler... I'm editing anyway, but I do think you haven't taken the context of this question and answer into account in your comments.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks. Just one last comment, I really think that while JCIP contains many Java-centric oddities, it also contains advice which is relevant to almost all programming languages. It's not the first time I hear "Hey it's JCIP, we're not doing Java so it's irrelevant", and I really think it's not true. Your comment about the context is valid and correct, I apologize for not noticing the date. Sometimes, it doesn't make sense to build the high level abstraction you need, since it's too much work, just use what exists to get the job done. Thanks and I apologize.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich: Not to worry - hopefully the edit ends up with a better answer anyway. Does the edit cover most of what you were after?I agree that JCIP advice can *often* be relevant in other platforms - but only if it's advising you to use something which is at least *available* on your platform :) My problem with implementing the high level abstraction myself would be that it's too difficult to get right - designing a high level abstraction for a *general* case is harder than doing *just what you need* for a specific case. If it's clear what the abstraction should be, that's great :)

Comment: @JonSkeet The edit covers it, thanks. Implementing a general performant concurrency framework is hard, I'm not sure that implementing framework to solve your problem, is harder than solving it with raw locks. Look at golang.org, with a single blocking queue, and a thread pool, you get a ton of expressibility (granted, select is tricky to implement, but just queue+thread pool is still very useful). Implementing those is not that hard, and you can copy implementation from books.

Comment: Understand this is an older answer and the concurrent collections render much of it moot - but locking large amounts of code just means your application isn't really doing parallel processing.  If you need to lock constantly to update object fields your design likely has larger problems - try to rework it using immutable data and you'll have a much more parallel solution that is thread safe.

Comment: @Mathieson: Sometimes you really *do* want to perform a bunch of code on the whole collection while remaining confident that nothing is going to change the collection though. And yes, that can reduce parallelism. I'm all for immutability and the many benefits it brings (not just in thread safety) but this answer was aimed at the choice between taking a lock at a higher level, or just using a "synchronized collection" (which is usually the wrong approach IMO - it's at least dangerous if used carelessly).

Comment: The synched collection might be a wrong approach, but I'd say it's less wrong than simply using locks to get the code to work badly.  It's now hiding a bad design.  Semantics overall though - and luckily with the better collections the easiest path is a better one.

Comment: @Mathieson: You're making a lot of assumptions when you say it's a bad design. There are situations where it's an entirely reasonable design, and will actually hardly dent performance at all. It's not like the concurrent collections don't have trade-offs too.

Comment: Overusing lock scope is a bad design, as at that point you're basically running a single-threaded application, but with the complexity of managing your locks.  That is objectively always a worse design.  Now what is 'overusing' is up for debate, but your design should always aim to reduce the need of locks if possible.

Comment: @Mathieson: Yes - my point is that you're *assuming* that my answer is "overusing" lock scope, when we don't have *slightly* enough evidence of what the OP is actually doing. Your idea of "overusing" appears to be "running the whole application in a lock" (otherwise it wouldn't be "basically running a single-threaded application" - just because there's some contention doesn't mean *permanent* contention).

Comment: My idea isn't mine, it's the simple fact that as the amount of locking increases, the application approaches the same performance as a single threaded application.  Therefore a design which minimizes the amount of locking needed is better from a performance standpoint.  I don't understand how you can see that as controversial, but to each their own.

Comment: @Mathieson: What I object to is you going from my answer to the idea that I'm encouraging *everything* to be done under a lock the whole time. But if you think my answer is unhelpful, go ahead and downvote it and add your own answer. I'm done here.

Answer (score 37):

There's a major problem with the `Synchronized` methods in the old collection library, in that they synchronize at too low a level of granularity (per method rather than per unit-of-work).

There's a classic race condition with a synchronized queue, shown below where you check the `Count` to see if it is safe to dequeue, but then the `Dequeue` method throws an exception indicating the queue is empty. This occurs because each individual operation is thread-safe, but the value of `Count` can change between when you query it and when you use the value.

```
object item;
if (queue.Count > 0)
{
    // at this point another thread dequeues the last item, and then
    // the next line will throw an InvalidOperationException...
    item = queue.Dequeue();
}
```

You can safely write this using a manual lock around the entire unit-of-work (i.e. checking the count *and* dequeueing the item) as follows:

```
object item;
lock (queue)
{
    if (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        item = queue.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

So as you can't safely dequeue anything from a synchronized queue, I wouldn't bother with it and would just use manual locking.

.NET 4.0 should have a whole bunch of properly implemented thread-safe collections, but that's still nearly a year away unfortunately.

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue<T>`  of course now exists - this problem is solved with `TryDequeue()` so you can't make this mistake

Answer (score 16):

There's frequently a tension between demands for 'thread safe collections' and the requirement to perform multiple operations on the collection in an atomic fashion.

So Synchronized() gives you a collection which won't smash itself up if multiple threads add items to it simultaneously, but it doesn't magically give you a collection that knows that during an enumeration, nobody else must touch it.

As well as enumeration, common operations like "is this item already in the queue? No, then I'll add it" also require synchronisation which is wider than just the queue.

Answer (score 7):

This way we don't need to lock the queue just to find out it was empty.

```
object item;
if (queue.Count > 0)
{
  lock (queue)
  {
    if (queue.Count > 0)
    {
       item = queue.Dequeue();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear to me that using a lock(...) {...} lock is the right answer.

> **To guarantee the thread safety of the Queue, all operations must be done through this wrapper only.**

If other threads access the queue without using .Synchronized(), then you'll be up a creek - unless all your queue access is locked up.

Comment: The wrapper the article is talking about is the Synchronized() wrapper, not the lock() wrapper.

Comment: Right - but using it in one thread doesn't make the other threads compliant.  The point is that if you rely on .Synch() only, you'll have an easier time screwing yourself.