# What is the benefit of this .Net pattern

Tags: .net, synchronization, thread-safety, design-patterns

I was looking for a pattern to be able to provide both a thread-safe and unsafe version of the same class.  The technical aspects of this are pretty obvious.  I guess was hoping to find naming/access conventions etc...

So I find this pattern everywhere in the 'Systems.Collections' namespace:

```
public class WhatEv
{
    private class SyncWhatEv : WhatEv
    {
        // overrides IsSyncronized = true
        // overrides whatever else to make it thread safe
    }

    public virtual bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return false; }  
    } 

    public static WhatEv Synchronized(WhatEv whatEv)
    {
        return new SyncWhatEv(whatEv);
    }
}
```

There are a number of classes that implement this: HashTable, Queue, ArrayList, Stack, etc...  I understand the inheritance.  But why make it a private, nested class and make the user jump through a hoop to get to it?  Are there any benefits to doing it this way?

Comment: Thanks for your input so far.  I'm just trying to imagine a scenario where the user of this wants to receive the base class without knowing it's thread-safe.  If the receiver is a thread, it should require the thread-safe version, right?  if the receiver isn't, then why would it care?

Comment: If you will be accessing it from two threads, the both need to be using the same synchronized instance. You can't just have the receiver use a synchronized instance, and the main thread use the non-sync'd version. So if there is any chance of the object being accessed by another thread, it should be synchronized. But see Joel's answer for one potential problem.

Comment: @Naked - Agreed.  But SyncWhatEv inherits WhatEv.  So the same instance of SyncWhatEv could be utilized on the main thread as type WhatEv and required by the worker thread as type SyncWhatEv.  Only, this isn't possible because SyncWhatEv is private.  Currently the thread would have to double-check IsSynchronized and throw if false.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After pondering this for the weekend, and after getting no further responses.  I've decided the answer is: MS be crazy y'all.  The whole point of offering a synchronize version of the object is for thread safety, yet a thread has no way at compile time to require a thread safe version of the object.  The validation of this object has to take place at runtime, which is... bogus.

Thanks to everyone for their input.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Lovely. A -1 for no reason.  If I'm not correct, then show me how I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, a thread-safe version of the object (i.e. Hashtable, Queue) is not needed. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to add the overhead needed to make it thread-safe by default. Using the Synchronized method, allows users that need thread-safety to get a thread-safe version.

The synchronized version of the object doesn't add any additional functionality, other than thread-safety. They don't expose any new members, nor does knowing their underlying type really help. So they are made private and simply "look" like their public/base class.

Comment: If you're going to the expense of creating a thread safe version why not dispense with the non-threasafe version and only maintain one version?

Comment: @BenCr - Because there is a performance hit to ensure thread-safety. As I said, in general most cases don't need thread-safety, but it's there when you do. Also, the way most are coded, you can usually fix something in say Hashtable and it would also be fixed in the private thread-safe version. Since the latter is only concerned with ensure the proper locks are obtained.

Comment: @BenCr, I hear what you are saying.  I'm not overly paranoid of the performance cost of a lock, but my class is something that could be used extensively in a single threaded context and occasionally in a threaded context (like most of those classes, I'm sure).  Seems overkill to have all of the locking when 90% of the time it isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, this is a good idea, and @CodeNaked has a good explanation. In practice, there are still problems with this. For example, if you need to make 2 calls into your thread-safe class and need thread safety for both calls combined, you still need to do a lock. Good explanation in this SO item: [In C# would it be better to use Queue.Synchronized or lock() for thread safety?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338712/in-c-would-it-be-better-to-use-queue-synchronized-or-lock-for-thread-safety)

Comment: Excellent link.  I agree that doing the locking yourself is a more refined way to go.  I still think, as a pattern, it just doesn't make sense to me.