# Queue Syncronization and operations in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

If a Queue is syncronized:

```
var _item = Queue.Synchronized(new Queue());
```

can I call methods like Enqueue and Dequeue on it without using lock statements?

My current code is:

```
lock (_item.SyncRoot)
{
    _item.Enqueue(obj);
}
```

Can I thread-safely use:

```
_item.Enqueue(obj);
var item = _item.Dequeue();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `Enqueue` and the call to `Dequeue` are thread safe.
However, your sample code is not:
Between the call to `Enqueue` and the call to `Dequeue` there could have been a thread switch. This means, that `item` might be another instance than `obj` or the call to `Dequeue` throws an exception, because it now is empty.

To make your sample code thread safe, you still need to lock explicitly:

```
lock(_item.SyncRoot)
{
    _item.Enqueue(obj);
    var item = _item.Dequeue);
}
```

Only now it is guaranteed, that `item` reference-equals `obj` in all circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

That is pretty much what `SynchronizedQueue` does, but there is a problem... typically you need to check the `.Count` ***and*** `.Dequeue()` in one atomic unit - not check the `.Count` (one unit) then `.Dequeue()` (another unit) - you can't trust `.Count` *at all* once the lock is surrendered, and `.Dequeue()` will throw if another thread has stolen the work.

Maybe try [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) in 4.0 (with `.TryDequeue()`), or use `Queue<T>` and `lock`.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized.aspx)

> To guarantee the thread safety of the
>   Queue, all operations must be done
>   through this wrapper only.
>
> Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is
>   synchronized, other threads can still
>   modify the collection, which causes
>   the enumerator to throw an exception.
>   To guarantee thread safety during
>   enumeration, you can either lock the
>   collection during the entire
>   enumeration or catch the exceptions
>   resulting from changes made by other
>   threads.

Just as John Skeet's answer suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338712/in-c-would-it-be-better-to-use-queue-synchronized-or-lock-for-thread-safety/338761#338761), you might be better or using locking since enumerating might cause an exception.

Gregs [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338712/in-c-would-it-be-better-to-use-queue-synchronized-or-lock-for-thread-safety/338857#338857) also talks about what Marc mentions with the `Count` not being thread safe.